# facebook login currentAccessToken return null

Tags: facebook-access-token

There is a problem with use Facebook SDK login.
The code is there.in AppDeledate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    BOOL flag = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    …………
   return flag
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation{
    BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                  openURL:url
                                                        sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                               annotation:annotation
                    ];
    return handled;
}
```

And in the costomer VC

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    loginButton.delegate = self;
    loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
    loginButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
}
```

when I called [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] after loginbutton click and login success(In my facebook setting applications i found the app exist), the Token always null